# iconv() 32 bit vs 64 bit on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, utf-8, iconv

I have a bit of code that uses iconv() on Linux to validate a string as being UTF-8 encoded.  The conversion I create like:

```
iconv_t c = iconv_open("UTF-8","UTF-8");
```

I run iconv() like:

```
int status = iconv(c, &fromArray, (size_t*)&inSize, &toArray, (size_t*)&outSize);
```

I then take the string to have valid UTF-8 if `status` is not -1.

This compiles and works fine in a 32 bit environment (where it was initially developed and tested).  However I now have a requirement to get this working in a 64 bit environment (to be specific the 64 bit flavor of Fedora 14 I believe).  When I compile and run a test on this there `status` is always `-1` and I always get an `EILSEQ` error in `errno`, even for the same string which the 32 bit compile says is fine.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Whilst it may not be an issue, what is `inSize` and `outSize`? The reason I ask is that casting them to `(size_t *)` may cause issues if the type is not same size as `size_t`.

Comment: Indeed, that's what the issue was.  They were originally `int`s when they should have been `size_t`s.  Changing the type stopped the crash.  Of course, at the time I write this the code that did this is now defunct, but I wanted to confirm this for posterity.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently had experienced same issue. Casting to (size_t*) is more (very) likely the root cause. 
The problem even could be easy simulated with next code:

```
cat >Makefile <<EOF
all: build test clean

clean:
    rm -f *.o core* t32 t64
test: build
    @echo ; echo "run_32bit version:" ; ./t32
    @echo ; echo "run_64bit version:" ; ./t64
build:
    g++ -m32 t.cpp -o t32 -Wall -O0 -g
    g++      t.cpp -o t64 -Wall -O0 -g
EOF

cat >t.cpp <<EOF
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iconv.h>

char buff_toArray [BUFSIZ];
char buff_fromArray [] = \
"<TESTS_STRINGS>\
    <T_VERIFICATION_STRINGS/>\
</TESTS_STRINGS>";

void iconv_test ( const char* desc, size_t* size )
{
   printf ("%s = size[%zu]\n",desc, (*size) );
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

 char* toArray = &buff_toArray[0];
 char* fromArray = &buff_fromArray[0];

 const int inSize_const = 61;
 short inSize_short = (short) sizeof(buff_fromArray);
 int inSize_int = (int) sizeof(buff_fromArray);
 unsigned int inSize_uint = (unsigned int) sizeof(buff_fromArray);
 long inSize_long = (long) sizeof(buff_fromArray);
 long long inSize_llong = (long long) sizeof(buff_fromArray);
 size_t inSize_size_t = sizeof(buff_fromArray);

 printf ("fake iconv usage:\n");
 iconv_test((const char*) "inSize_const", (size_t*)&inSize_const);
 iconv_test((const char*) "inSize_short", (size_t*)&inSize_short);
 iconv_test((const char*) "inSize_int", (size_t*)&inSize_int);
 iconv_test((const char*) "inSize_uint", (size_t*)&inSize_uint);
 iconv_test((const char*) "inSize_long", (size_t*)&inSize_long);
 iconv_test((const char*) "inSize_llong", (size_t*)&inSize_llong);
 iconv_test((const char*) "inSize_size_t", &inSize_size_t);

 printf ("real iconv usage:\n");
 int inSize = sizeof(buff_fromArray);
 int outSize = sizeof(buff_toArray);

 iconv_t c = iconv_open("UTF-8","UTF-8");
 int status = iconv(c, &fromArray, (size_t*)&inSize, &toArray, (size_t*)&outSize);
 printf ("status=[%d], errno=[%d] \n", status, errno );

 printf ("result string:\n");
 for(size_t i = 0; i <= sizeof(buff_toArray); i++) { printf ("%c", buff_toArray[i]); }
 printf ("\n");

 int close_status =  iconv_close(c);
 printf ("close status=[%d], errno=[%d] \n", close_status, errno );

 return 0;
}
EOF
```